# Windows is asking for password to browse the available file shares on Samba

Tags: ubuntu, passwords, network-shares, samba

Server: Samba on Ubuntu 12.04, with `security = user`.

A variety of file shares - some need to be accessible by guests, some are `allowed  users = user1`.

Client: Windows XP, on same workgroup as the server.

**Start** → **Run** → `\\192.168.1.240` brings up a Windows dialog box asking for username and password, before it's even displayed the list of file shares available on the server.  (Supplying user1's password gets past this point, but I think the password shouldn't be required yet)

What could be causing this?  How to fix this?

Ideal result: `\\192.168.1.240` displays the list of shares (without any credentials), and password is only needed to access the ones with `allowed  users` or `guest ok = no` in `smb.conf`.

Comment: I had the problem that the windows username was identical to the unix username on the machine running samba. Samba then imported the unix username and therefor always asked for the password. An easy fix was to remove the samba username via `pdbedit -x -u <username>`. Also see http://serverfault.com/questions/575394/samba-public-share-windows-keeps-asking-for-password - the rest was taken care of via `map to guest = bad user` in the smb.conf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're going to get prompted for authentication because of the security mode you selected "security = user".  To get what you want, I'd recommend Share Level Security.  A detailed description as well as instructions on what to do can be found here:

http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/ServerType.html#id2559114

Additionally, the site referenced describes the two samba security modes in detail.  So that should help you balance security and ease of use to your own requirements.

You can also add this to your smb.conf:

```
security = user
map to guest = Bad User
```

By adding that line, you're telling the server that any user who isn't accounted for is to be treated as the guest.

Comment: So basically, guest access isn't possible once you've selected security=user?

Comment: Well, there is a way, but it's not recommended due to the inherant security aspects. However, I've updated my answer with it

Comment: So they do similar things, but the 'map to guest' route doesn't give "user=share is deprecated" warnings (like http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1962617 ). Given that in this case we want to allow unauthenticated access to particular shares, are there any other security problems?

Comment: @OJW, not that I can think of.  Just be conscious of what *nobody* has access to.